# Complex solution of the equation ${z^6} + \left( {1 + 2i} \right){z^3} + i - 1 = 0$

Tags: complex-numbers

Find all the complex solution of the equation ${z^6} + \left( {1 + 2i} \right){z^3} + i - 1 = 0$ and express in Euler form

My approach is as follow ${z^3} = T \Rightarrow {T^2} + \left( {1 + 2i} \right)T + i - 1 = 0$
$T = \frac{{ - \left( {1 + 2i} \right) \pm \sqrt {{{\left( {1 + 2i} \right)}^2} - 4\left( {i - 1} \right)} }}{2} \Rightarrow T = \frac{{ - \left( {1 + 2i} \right) \pm \sqrt {1 + 4{i^2} + 4i - 4\left( {i - 1} \right)} }}{2}$

$ \Rightarrow T = \frac{{ - \left( {1 + 2i} \right) \pm \sqrt {4{i^2} + 5} }}{2} \Rightarrow {z^3} = \frac{{ - \left( {1 + 2i} \right) \pm \sqrt {4{i^2} + 5} }}{2}$

Not able to proceed form here and not able to convert it into Euler form

Comment: You really ought to know that $i^2=-1$.

Comment: Yes I missed this step , now it is clear but at the end I get $z^3=i$ & $z^3=-(1+i)$

Comment: @SamarImamZaidi And are you having any sort of trouble solving those two equations?

Comment: Just take them to polar form (because it easier to solve) and solve the order-three-roots of those two numbers.

Comment: @Samar Imam Zaidi OH! you lost interest in your problem, !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$z^3=\frac{-(1+2i)\pm 1}{2}=-i,-1+i$$
Case 1: $$z^3=e^{i(2m+3)\pi/2} \implies z_m=e^{i(2m+3)\pi/6}, m=0,1,2$$
$$z_0=e^{i\pi/2}=i,~ z_1=e^{5i\pi/6}=i 
\omega, ~ z_2=e^{7i\pi/2}=i \omega^2~~~~~(1),$$
where $\omega$ is cube root of unity.

Case 2: $$Z^3=\sqrt{2}~ e^{i(2n+3/4)\pi} \implies Z_n=2^{1/6}~ e^{i(2n+3/4)\pi/3}, n=0,1,2$$
$$Z_0=2^{1/6} e^{3i\pi/4}, Z_1=2^{1/6} e^{11i\pi/12}, Z_2=2^{1/6} e^{19i\pi/12}=-2^{1/6} e^{7i\pi/12} ~~~~(2).$$
Funally, (1) and (2) give all six roots of the required 6th degree  equation.

Answer (score 0):

We have $$(z^3+1+i)(z^3+i)=0,$$ which gives $$z^3=\sqrt2(\cos225^{\circ}+i\sin225^{\circ})$$ or
$$z^3=1(\cos270^{\circ}+i\sin270^{\circ}).$$
Can you end it now?

Actually, in $\mathbb C$ $$\sqrt{1}=\{1,-1\},$$ which says that we can write here:
$$T=\frac{-(1+2i)+\sqrt1}{2}.$$